# Why isn't docker-compose fully executing the contents of a container that another container is dependent upon?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I want to start a Python container dependent on a database container.  But I would like the Python container to start only after the sql server container has fully executed.  I built this docker-compose.yml file ...

```
version: "3.2"
  
services:
  sql-server-db:
    restart: always
    build: ./
    container_name: sql-server-db
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    env_file: /Users/davea/my_project/api/tests/.test_env
    ports:
      - 3900:1433
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=password
      - DB_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - DB_NAME=my_db
      - DB_USER=SA
      - DB_PASS=password
    volumes:
      - ../../CloudDB/CloudDB:/sqlscripts

  python:
    restart: always
    build: ../ 
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
    volumes:
    - /Users/davea/my_project/api:/my-app
    depends_on:
      - sql-server-db
```

Below is my Dockerfile for the sql server container ...

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
  
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install unzip -y

RUN apt-get install tzdata
ENV TZ=America/New_York
RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
RUN date
RUN echo "========="


# Install sqlpackage, needed for deplying dacpac file
RUN wget -progress=bar:force -q -O sqlpackage.zip https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=873926 \
    && unzip -qq sqlpackage.zip -d /opt/sqlpackage \
    && chmod +x /opt/sqlpackage/sqlpackage

# Create work directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/work

WORKDIR /usr/work

# Copy all SQL scripts into working directory
COPY . /usr/work/

# Grant permissions for the import-data script to be executable
RUN chmod +x /usr/work/import-data.sh

RUN pwd
CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

but I'm noticing something strange.  The SQL server container does not seem to be fully executing all the commands in the entrypoint.sh file.  I see this output ...

```
...
Removing intermediate container 72550d896ede
 ---> ae6b93ca884e
Step 14/15 : RUN pwd
 ---> Running in f229ef6fec4c
/usr/work
Removing intermediate container f229ef6fec4c
 ---> 7758242bbd95
Step 15/15 : CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
 ---> Running in 76fa5c8308e3
Removing intermediate container 76fa5c8308e3
 ---> 567633ad757f
Successfully built 567633ad757f
Successfully tagged microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
WARNING: Image for service sql-server-db was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Building python
Step 1/17 : FROM python:3.8-slim
```

Below are the contents of the entrypoint.sh file.  Is there another way I can structure things so taht the commands are executed?  I'm noticing the Python container doesn't seem to recognize the SQL server container either.

```
#!/bin/bash -l
  
/usr/work/import-data.sh & /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

Is there somethign else I need to do to get the shell script from my sql server container to fully execute?

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of depends_on option is incorrect, or perhaps not working the way in which you intend it to work.
See: [Documentation of depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on). It clearly state it does not wait for the database to be ready in case of sql servers.

Depends_on implies only to wait until the service is up and running.

> - depends_on does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before starting web - only until they have been started. If you need to wait for a service to be ready, see Controlling startup order for more on this problem and strategies for solving it.

You will benefit to create some sort of manual "wait-for-it" script ([as seen in this docker-compose example](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)) before starting python container.